# Clickable Items From ListView RSS Reader

Tags: android, listview, rss, android-webview

I was following an online mobile tutorial about RSS Readers, and before I could go through the complete tutorial it was removed. I have waited for some time now (it hasn't come back!), and I have tried to complete the code myself. On my own, I have been able to get my app to parse data and display out into a ListView. I need some help making it so that after any item is clicked, it opens up a WebView and displays the content associated to the URL attached to that item. Can someone tell me what I am missing and doing wrong here? I have been doing my best to fill in the blanks, but the items I click from ListView still do nothing.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

ListView feedListView;
List<FeedStructure> rssStr;
private FeedListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    feedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    feedListView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    RssFeedTask rssTask = new RssFeedTask();
    rssTask.execute();
}

//setup asynctask
private class RssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    String response = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            String feed = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/drxeno/home";
            XMLHandler rh = new XMLHandler();
            rssStr = rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }   
        return response;        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (rssStr != null) {
            adapter = new FeedListAdapter(MainActivity.this, rssStr);
            feedListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        Dialog.dismiss();
    }   
}

//@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, rssStr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebviewActivity.class);
    new Bundle();
    intent.putExtra("b", rssStr.get(pos).getLink());

    //get the selected item and do the further process  
    lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    ((FeedStructure) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos)).getLink();
    }   
}
```

FeedStructure

```
public class FeedStructure {

private String title;
private String pubDate;
private String imgLink;
private String creator;
private String link;
private long item;

//@param item set item
public void setItem(long item) {
    this.item = item;
}

//@return item
public long getItem() {
    return item;
}

//@param title set title
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

//@return title
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

//truncate title
public String toString() {
    if (title.length() > 10) {
        return title.substring(0, 10) + "...";
    }
    return title;
}

//@param pubDate set pubDate
public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

//@return pubDate
public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

//@param imgLink set imgLink
public void setImgLink(String imgLink) {
    this.imgLink = imgLink;
}

//@return imgLink
public String getImgLink() {
    return imgLink;
}

//@param creator set creator
public void setCreator(String creator) {
    this.creator = creator;
}

//@return creator
public String getCreator() {
    return creator;
}   

//@param creator set URL
public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

//@return URL
public String getLink() {
    return link;
}
```

}

Handler

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private FeedStructure feedStr = new FeedStructure();
private List<FeedStructure> rssList = new ArrayList<FeedStructure>();

private int acticlesAdded = 0;

private static final int ARTICLES_LIMIT = 50;
StringBuilder chars = new StringBuilder();

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) 
        throws SAXException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);
    chars = new StringBuilder();
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        feedStr.setTitle(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
        feedStr.setPubDate(chars.toString());
    }       
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("creator")) {
        feedStr.setCreator(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
        feedStr.setLink(chars.toString());
    }
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        rssList.add(feedStr);

        feedStr = new FeedStructure();
        acticlesAdded++;
        if (acticlesAdded >= ARTICLES_LIMIT) {
            throw new SAXException();
        }
    }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}

public List<FeedStructure> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        url = new URL(feedUrl);
        xr.setContentHandler(this);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) { Log.d(TAG, "IOException");
    } catch (SAXException e) { Log.d(TAG, "SAXException");
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { 
    }   
    return rssList; 
}
```

}

Adapter

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedStructure> {

List<FeedStructure> metaData = null;
public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedStructure> metaDataParse) {
    super(activity, 0, metaDataParse);
    metaData = metaDataParse;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_format, null);
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title_format);
    TextView creatorTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.creator_format);
    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date_format);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_format);
        try {
            titleTextView.setText(metaData.get(position).getTitle());
            creatorTextView.setText("Creator: " + metaData.get(position).getCreator());

            //reformat current date into another format
            if (metaData.get(position).getPubDate() != null) {
                String pubDate = metaData.get(position).getPubDate();

                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

                try {
                    Date pDate = df.parse(pubDate);
                    dateTextView.setText("Published: " + df.format(pDate));
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                }
            }

            //pull in ImgLink, if there is no image use static image
            if (metaData.get(position).getImgLink() != null) {
                URL feedImage = new URL (metaData.get(position).getImgLink().toString());
                                    if (!feedImage.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)feedImage.openConnection();
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
                } else {
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);
                }
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
        }
        return rowView;
    }
```

}

WebView Activity

```
public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);  

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String KEY_LINK = b.getString("link");

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

    webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true); 
    webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true); 
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.loadUrl(KEY_LINK);

    final Activity MyActivity = this;

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            MyActivity.setTitle("Loading test...");
            MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); 
            if (progress == 100) {
                MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }   
        }
    });

}
```

}

WebViewClient

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

public MyWebViewClient(WebviewActivity webviewActivity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.ljtatum.blog.com")) {

        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    return true;
}
```

}

I have been trying to fill in the blanks for weeks, and I contacted the author several times. Hopefully you can help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this on your main activity:

```
feedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
feedListView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
// Add this line
feedListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Another piece of the puzzle I was missing. I added it, and I'm sure I needed this. But my items still do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Quick glance says that you need to move some code from your OnClickMethod to your onCreate().

Example:

```
// Find the ListView from the XML
list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.faq_list);
// Set the vertical edges to fade
list.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

// Create a new adapter
adapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feed);
// Set the adapter to the list
list.setAdapter(adapter);

// Set on item click listener to the ListView
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Do your onClick
    }
});
```

That's how I wrote my RSS stuff, with that simply in onCreate, whereas you have it split up across your Async, which isn't the best way to do it (and probably makes it harder to track a bug).

Try working from the code above and see if it helps you out, any questions just drop a comment. :)

**EDIT:**

Generally the way to go is to make your AsyncTask return your parsed feed and in your onCreate do `feed = new AsyncTask(params);` and then follow the code I posted above.

This should work because I'm looking at one of my RSS projects right now :p

Comment: I think that if I move public void onItemClick(Adapter<?>...) to onCreate Android will say that onItemClick is unimplemented, because it wants to see this outside of the OnCreate. I do agree that I probably have code misplaced, but I am not certain of the proper arrangement.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder As long as you override it like I did and put your method in there it should be fine. But your ListView stuff has to be outside the onClick and just in onCreate. Also updated my answer with more info.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question. There were two missing parts. The below piece needed `startActivity(intent)`. Without this line, even with proper click event code, `WebviewActivity` would not be able to launch.

```
//@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, rssStr);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);


Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebviewActivity.class);
new Bundle();
intent.putExtra("b", rssStr.get(pos).getLink());

//get the selected item and do the further process  
lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
((FeedStructure) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos)).getLink();
startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

And as "Chor WaiChun" said, I needed to also add `feedListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`.

Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{...}
```

Hope it works.